# Is there anyway to Extract the Particular User's Contacts Using the user's nsf file?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

In Lotus Notes For Every User there is one nsf file will be created with the userid name as a file name. I want to Extract the Contact details using that nsf file Using Java Lotus Notes API.. (If my userid is user1 means the **nsf** file created in **user1.nsf**).. Is it possible to extract all the contacts of that user using the user's nsf file?

Comment: Do you refer to the user's mail file when you say "the user's nsf file"?
When you say "contact details" do you then refer to the user's own details (such as first name, last name, email address, user name)?

It sounds like to you need to look up the user's contact details in the central Domino Directory (names.nsf on the server)

Comment: I think my question is not clear... The user1 created a new contact who is already have an account in the lotus notes or some other mail server say user2. I want to extract the details of user2 using the user1.nsf file.... I don't need the user1 details.... For that how do I achieve... Ok If I use names.nsf file how to get the contacts created in user1 account?

Comment: So user1 creates a contact in his own address book?

Comment: Yes you are right... So I need to get that user details in that Address book...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tricky part here isn't reading the contact documents, it's *finding* the database itself.  Depending on the installation, the contacts could be either on the server or local on their workstation.

If you're running from a server agent, you can only access the databases on the current server, or another server your credentials have access to.  However, sometimes by default the user's contacts are put into a local database on their workstation and you can only reach them from code running in the user's context.

If that's the case, you have no choice but to find a way to run something on each user's workstation.  You could

a) have the user replicate the names.nsf to the server, or

b) synchronize the contacts using the mail action.

For "a", you might send a special email with a LotusScript button in it to automate the replication.  I've seen that method used in email migrations when using Quest software's migration tool, and it works well.

For "b", if you have a recent enough version of Notes you may follow [these instructions](http://web4.uwindsor.ca/its/faq/id/213) to enabling the sychronize contacts task on the replicator.  Ohterwise you'll need to instruct the users how to synchronize contacts using the actions menu.  One the contacts are synchronized, a copy of the contact information will be contained in the user's mail file, which will be available on the mail server.  You can then simply access the contacts view to read the documents.

Comment: Thank you Ken... It is working... After Synchronize I have used the user1.nsf file and used the contacts view I am getting the contacts count properly.... Thank you so much....

Comment: Hi, Using the Contact view I can able to get the contacts in ViewEntryCollection format. from that I was getting each EntryCollection as a document. Is there any API or program used to convert that document as .vcf file?

Comment: No API that I'm aware of in Lotus Notes, unfortunately.  Looks like the vcf files would be easy to create, though:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard

Comment: Hi All, After Synchronizing I can get the contact and document attached in the contacts also... But now I got the issue of getting new attachment added for the contact... I can get the attachment of already in the contacts.. If any new attachment is added, not able to get the new attachment...

Comment: Hi All, The Issue above said is now working fine... After go through this link http://lotus.udayton.edu/udit/lotus/homepage.nsf/Lookup/9D40BDE581BC74AF85256C760058E4B6?OpenDocument found that whenever there is a change in the contacts in lotus notes, we are in need to resynchronize the contacts...